# How can I force TabBar to show in all App screens react-navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to show the Bottom TabBar in every screen in my app, but i can't find a way to do it in RN V5 yet,

So When i tried to use `tabBarVisible` like this

```
<BottomTab.Navigator
      lazy={false}
      tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} />}
      screenOptions={({route}) => (
             console.log('route', route), it's just log the five bottom component i have
             {
             tabBarVisible: ({routes}) => {
             let tabBarVisible = false;
             console.log('screens', routes); // Not log anything!
             return {tabBarVisible};
            },
          }
         )}
        ....
       >
       ... 5 Tabs here
</BottomTab.Navigator>
```

So How can i handle this case? and access to other stack screens?

just to minimize the code snippet in question

here's the [full Root file](https://gist.github.com/anastely/3f5c5ee82eaa1ac0e85819c63409127f) code, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `tabBar` to be shown in every screen of the app, you need to make it your root navigator and then all screens will be under that navigator, so the `tabBar` will be visible in all screens.

Comment: Are you see the gist file?

Comment: Yeah, I see it. With such a configuration you will never have that BottomTab on every screen because it is inside another screen, so it will be visible as long as you are in that screen and nested ones. This concept is easy - you see the `tabBar` only when you are in a screen that is inside the BottomTab navigator.